# Is there a way to simulate network conditions from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, networking, browser, developer-tools

In the developer tools of Firefox, one can choose to simulate conditions like certain types of mobile data connections. Is there a way to activate this from JavaScript, without requiring users to open up the developer console?

Comment: I think not. But, depending on your exact use case, maybe you can implement a service worker in JavaScript that simulates request problems.

Comment: @CherryDT - Well, it could be activated via a permission or something. That service worker approach is a good idea, though, if you want to flesh it out and post an answer. Very clever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your use case, you could either

1. Install a service worker that listens to the “fetch” event, then calls `event.respondWith` with a delay (HTTPS required);
2. Intercept a call to fetch / XMLHttpRequest in the application scope to do the same thing (overwrite `window.fetch` and/or `window.XMLHttpRequest`) - note this won’t affect images / resources loaded directly from HTML;
3. Set a HTTP cookie or header and make your server / delay before responding (lots of users doing this may reduce server concurrency however)

Note that if you want to emulate this kind of behaviour with a streamed resource (e.g. progressive JPEGs, HTML), your best bet is the service worker route, where you can construct a `ReadableStream` directly (see here for some inspiration: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/06/sw-readablestreams).

For the actual streaming behaviour itself I would consider using something like an RxJs pipeline, which would make it easy for you to introduce delays, arbitrary stops etc. to simulate different network conditions.

Comment: Thanks! I really like the ideas, though I'm not yet sure whether to accept it because it doesn't actually activate the network conditions simulation. I guess if it's impossible at the moment, I should probably just accept a workaround until such time as it becomes possible. I'll wait a bit for other answers in case someone discovers it is possible. If I haven't accepted this by Tuesday, please remind me ;)

Comment: If you want to actually activate those functions, then no, those APIs are not exposed to application code. As a whole they are quite privileged - they can inspect things like HTTP only cookies (used to protect auth tokens from XSS), so anything like that could be a sidechannel to attacks. Your only other option on that front AFAIK is a custom browser extension, which can do more privileged things than untrusted JavaScript.

Comment: @Luc - found any other ways to do this?

Comment: Ah indeed, nope, this seems to be the way to do this currently. Thanks again :)